# Visual Studio 2015 100-percent CPU usage with Node

Tags: c#, node.js, visual-studio

I have a particular project that uses 100% of the CPU whenever it is open. You can see, below, the CPU is being used heavily by Visual Studio and Node. I have disabled several VS extensions but still have the problem. Also it continues even if I delete gulp.js, package.json, and bower.json files. It is a C# web project. This doesn’t happen with other VS projects on my machine.

Restarting Visual Studio doesn't help, but restarting my whole PC does make the problem go away, for a while.

[image: 100% CPU usage]

Comment: This may be related to Web Essentials. I installed update 0.5.168 today and rebooted and so far it is working OK.

Comment: I removed Web Essentials with no improvement. Removed some other extensions including ReSharper; I'll see how that goes.

Comment: None of the above things helped. I reinstalled Visual Studio 2015, and this may have fixed the problem.

Comment: That didn't work either. I upgraded from Windows 7 to 10; maybe that will help.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by upgrading from Windows 7 to 10. I chose the option to keep my existing applications; Enterprise edition; it went smoothly.